# How to display vertical text in column headers without text overflow and also without expanding the width of the other columns

Tags: html, css, sass

I want to build a table with vertical column headers as shown in the image [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V9IFT.png). But the text in the column header can be variable so when I have more text in the column header the text overflows.

My question is how to increase the width of that particular column so that text doesn't overflow.

[here](https://jsfiddle.net/SSV0811/3r9h535x/) is link to my code. I have also pasted the code below.

```
<table id="example" class="dataTable display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="rank">Rank</th>
            <th class="wider">User Inserted Title Name</th>
            <th class="rotate"><div><div class="textH">Fisrt Number second Number</div></div></th>
            <th class="rotate"><div><div class="textH">Fisrt Number<br> Second Number</div></div></th>
            <th class="rotate"><div><div class="textH">Fisrt Number<br> Second Number</div></div></th>
            <th class="rotate"><div><div class="textH">Fisrt Number<br> Second Number</div></div></th>
            <th class="rotate"><div><div class="textH">Fisrt Number<br> Second Number</div></div></th>
            <th class="rotate"><div><div class="textH">Fisrt Number<br> Second Number</div></div></th>
            <th class="rotate"><div><div class="textH">Fisrt Number<br> Second Number</div></div></th>
            <th class="rotate"><div><div class="textH">Fisrt Number<br> Second Number</div></div></th>
            <th class="rotate"><div><div class="textH">Fisrt Number<br> Second Number</div></div></th>
            <th class="rotate"><div><div class="textH">Fisrt Number<br> Second Number</div></div></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>System Architect and Analyser</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>4</td>
            <td>6</td>
            <td>20</td>
            <td>5</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>4</td>
            <td>6</td>
            <td>20</td>
            <td>5</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>Accountant</td>
            <td>4</td>
            <td>13</td>
            <td>7</td>
            <td>11</td>
            <td>8</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>4</td>
            <td>6</td>
            <td>20</td>
            <td>5</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>Junior Technical Author</td>
            <td>5</td>
            <td>26</td>
            <td>9</td>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>19</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>4</td>
            <td>6</td>
            <td>20</td>
            <td>5</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
.dataTable th 
{
 word-wrap: break-word;
}
td, th 
{
border: 1px solid #000;
}
th.rank 
{
width: 20px !important;
}
th.wider 
{
/*width: 120px !important;*/
}
th.rotate 
{
height: 150px;
padding: 0px;
/*width: 20px !important;*/
font-weight: normal;
vertical-align:bottom;  
}
th.rotate > div 
{
-webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
-moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);
-ms-transform: rotate(-90deg);
-o-transform: rotate(-90deg);
width: 50px;
}

.textH
{
// overflow:visible:
height: 150px !important;
width: 150px !important;
text-align:left;   
}
```

Comment: another link to my code having overflow text https://jsfiddle.net/SSV0811/3r9h535x/2/

Answer (score 1):

Well, here what I would do: [Codepen](http://codepen.io/grebre0/pen/LWZmNb)

It takes a few lines of JavaScript. The idea is to calculate `width` and `height` via JS script. Also It should be modified if you want it fully responsive.

Answer (score 1):

If you combine `writing-mode: vertical-rl;` and `transform: rotate(-180deg);` it will work without setting a width

```css
.dataTable th {
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
td,th {
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
th.wider {
  /*width: 120px !important;*/
}
th.rotate {
  height: 150px;
  padding: 0px;
  font-weight: normal;
}
th.rotate > div {
  writing-mode: vertical-rl;
  transform: rotate(-180deg);
}
.textH {
  height: 150px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<table id="example" class="dataTable display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="rank">Rank</th>
      <th class="wider">User Inserted Title Name</th>
      <th class="rotate">
        <div>
          <div class="textH">Fisrt Number second Number</div>
        </div>
      </th>
      <th class="rotate">
        <div>
          <div class="textH">Fisrt Number
            <br> Second Number</div>
        </div>
      </th>
      <th class="rotate">
        <div>
          <div class="textH">Fisrt Number
            <br> Second Number</div>
        </div>
      </th>
      <th class="rotate">
        <div>
          <div class="textH">Fisrt Number
            <br> Second Number</div>
        </div>
      </th>
      <th class="rotate">
        <div>
          <div class="textH">Fisrt Number
            <br> Second Number</div>
        </div>
      </th>
      <th class="rotate">
        <div>
          <div class="textH">Fisrt Number
            <br> Second Number</div>
        </div>
      </th>
      <th class="rotate">
        <div>
          <div class="textH">Fisrt Number
            <br> Second Number</div>
        </div>
      </th>
      <th class="rotate">
        <div>
          <div class="textH">Fisrt Number
            <br> Second Number</div>
        </div>
      </th>
      <th class="rotate">
        <div>
          <div class="textH">Fisrt Number
            <br> Second Number</div>
        </div>
      </th>
      <th class="rotate">
        <div>
          <div class="textH">Fisrt Number
            <br> Second Number</div>
        </div>
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>System Architect and Analyser</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>6</td>
      <td>20</td>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>6</td>
      <td>20</td>
      <td>5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>Accountant</td>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>13</td>
      <td>7</td>
      <td>11</td>
      <td>8</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>6</td>
      <td>20</td>
      <td>5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>Junior Technical Author</td>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>26</td>
      <td>9</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>19</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>6</td>
      <td>20</td>
      <td>5</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Now the text vertical text aligns to the left in the header cell, can we align it  to the middle